# PHP Curl don't set headers

Tags: php, curl, nginx, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I have the following script:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?act=idx');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'; 
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Host: 4pda.ru';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0';


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$cookie_path = "./cookies.txt";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl); 
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)); //problem one

curl_close($curl);
var_dump($result);
```

I have two problems. First, PHP Curl does not set headers. It sends only these headers:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Host: 4pda.ru
Accept: */*
```

You can see that the php set headers incorrectly. 
The second problem is that the server returns the following content:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 14:26:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Although, I expect to get a html of page.

It is surprising that this script works fine on my home server (windows), and on my previous server. I think that my problems are due to incorrectly configure a new server. But I could be wrong.

I would be glad to any advice.
Regards, Denis.

**Update.** Thanks Ma Chuan, the first problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you use a wrong variable name in that set header line?

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

should read

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you for what you have found my typo. The first problem was solved. Unfortunately, the second problem is urgent.

Comment: In your request header example, I don't see the cookie header. Does the server require sending cookie for authorization?

Comment: no, you can go to http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?act=idx and get the content without cookies.

Comment: I ran your script and it worked as expected. It's possible that `4pda.ru` only rejects requests from your new server's ip.